# How to convert any negative value to zero with bitwise operators?

Tags: go, linked-list, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm writing the `PopBack()` operation for a LinkedList in Go, the code looks like this:

```golang
// PopBack will remove an item from the end of the linked list
func (ll *LinkedList) PopBack() {
    lastNode := &ll.node

    for *lastNode != nil && (*lastNode).next != nil {
        lastNode = &(*lastNode).next
    }

    *lastNode = nil

    if ll.Size() != 0 {
        ll.size -= 1
    }
}
```

I don't like the last `if` clause; if the size is zero we don't want to decrement to a negative value. I was wondering if there is a bitwise operation in which whatever the value is after the decrement, if it's *only negative* it should covert to a zero?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative values have the sign bit set, so you can do like this

```
ll.size += (-ll.size >> 31)
```

Suppose `ll.size` is **`int32`** and `ll.Size()` returns `ll.size`. Of course this also implies that *size is never negative*. When the size is positive then the right shift will sign-extend `-ll.size` to make it -1, otherwise it'll be 0

If `ll.size` is **`int64`** then change the shift count to 63. If `ll.size` is **`uint64`** you can simply [cast to `int64`](https://play.golang.org/p/EBFn_vyXBHr) if the size is never larger than 2<sup>63</sup>. But if the size can be that large (although almost impossible to occur in the far future) then things are [much more trickier](https://play.golang.org/p/09bqd0rGvYM):

```
mask := uint64(-int64(ll.size >> 63)) // all ones if ll.size >= (1 << 63)
ll.size = ((ll.size - 1) & mask) | ((ll.size + uint64(-int64(ll.size) >> 63)) & ^mask)
```

It's basically a [bitwise mux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplexer) that's usually used in [bithacks](https://graphics.stanford.edu/%7Eseander/bithacks.html) because you cannot cast bool to int without `if` in golang

Neither of these are quite readable at first glance so the `if` block is usually better

Comment: The `ll.size += (-ll.size >> 31)` is not returning the expected result. But
`ll.size -= 1;
ll.size += (ll.size >> 63)`
is returning it.

Comment: @Aziz of course. As I said I'm assuming `ll.size` is `int32` because there's no type information in your code. If it's `int64` then obviously you must shift 63 bits to copy the sign bit to all bits

Comment: My bad. But even in the case of 64 bit doing the same setup doesn't lead to the expected result. In the general case, it's incrementing the size rather than decrement.

Comment: @Aziz no `ll.size += (-ll.size >> 63)` will decrease when `ll.size` is **positive** and do nothing when it's 0. It depends on how you put the things together. So it'll stop decreasing when ll.size reaches 0. But it won't work if size is initialized to a negative value

Comment: Can you please help me out here? I'm doing the same as what you have done but instead of decrementing it's increasing the value to 3 instead of 1. https://play.golang.org/p/zxUnUKtTR5n

Comment: @Aziz I know why. You used `uint64` so the shift is always logical and `-size` is never negative. You must use a signed type for that, but then the size must be smaller than 2⁶³: https://play.golang.org/p/EBFn_vyXBHr see also my edit

Answer (score 1):

Trade a nil check in each iteration of the loop for a single nil check before the loop. With this change, the loop runs faster and the operator for updating size is subtraction.

```
func (ll *LinkedList) PopBack() {
    if ll.node == nil {
        return
    }
    lastNode := &ll.node
    for (*lastNode).next != nil {
        lastNode = &(*lastNode).next
    }
    *lastNode = nil
    ll.size -= 1
}
```